# React components don't update upon setState if I've reloaded the page since editing the files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jsx, mern

I've found many questions about React components not updating when someone sets the state, but most of the answers seem to be saying to do what I'm doing. In fact, what I'm doing does work--but only if I've edited and saved one of my React files (and thus rebooted the frontend server) since I last reloaded or changed the page. Basically, what I mean by that is, if I reload the page, this doesn't work, and if I click on a link (eg, to /messages), it doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is display a different like symbol (filled or outlined) based on whether or not someone has liked a post. Here's the jsx for that in the render method:

```js
{this.state.liked ? <Recommend onClick={this.handleLike}/> : <RecommendOutlined onClick={this.handleLike}/>}
```

"liked" is set as false in the constructor, and then updated in 1) `componentDidMount()` and 2) the like/unlike function. Here are those:

```js
componentDidMount () {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/p/likes/${this.state.post}`).then(res=>{
    console.log(res.data)
    let liked = false;
    for (let like of res.data) if (like.user == this.state.user) liked = true;
    this.setState({likes: res.data, liked})
  })
}

handleLike(event) {
  axios.post('http://localhost:3002/p/like',this.state).then(res=>{
    let liked = false;
    for (let like of res.data.likes) if (like.user == this.state.user) liked = true;
    this.setState({likes: res.data.likes, liked})
  })
}
```

They both use `setState()`, so the component should rerender automatically. `handleLike()` is bound in the constructor (meaning I did `this.handleLike = this.handleLike.bind(this);`), so it should be called (and it is).

And, most confusing of all, *this does work*. Just only in a specific scenario. So I don't know what's going on. It works after I update the file, and then if I reload the page it shows all of the posts as unliked (even though any console logging I do shows whether or not they're actually liked).

In case there's something I missed, here's the whole component:

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import {Recommend, RecommendOutlined} from '@mui/icons-material';

import style from './style.css'

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

class CommentForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            post: props.post, likes: [],  liked: false, comment: '', user: props.user
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleLike = this.handleLike.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/p/likes/${this.state.post}`).then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data)
            let liked = false;
            for (let like of res.data) if (like.user == this.state.user) liked = true;
            this.setState({likes: res.data, liked})
        })
        //this.setState({likes: ['o','e','raphaelmorgan'],liked: true})
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:3002/p/comment',this.state)
          .then(res=>{
              console.log(res.data)
              console.log(event.target);
              if (res.data.status == 'success') this.setState({comment: ''})
          });
    }
    handleLike(event) {
       console.log('liking post')
        axios.post('http://localhost:3002/p/like',this.state).then(res=>{
            let liked = false;
            for (let like of res.data.likes) if (like.user == this.state.user) liked = true;
            this.setState({likes: res.data.likes, liked})
        })
    }
    render() {
        let state = this.state;
        console.log(state.liked)
        return (
            <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center">
                <Grid item>{this.state.liked ? <Recommend onClick={this.handleLike}/> :
                  <RecommendOutlined onClick={this.handleLike}/>}</Grid>
                <Grid item><form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input name="comment" type="text" onInput={this.handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Comment" value={this.state.comment}/>
                </form></Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentForm;
```

**UPDATE:** So apparently the problem lies somewhere in assigning the props. The props.user is apparently only a thing when the page hasn't been reloaded since the server started. The props are being passed in from my Post component like so:

```js
<CommentForm post={this.props.id} user={this.state.user}/>
```

It seems the "user" prop isn't actually being sent, though, because it shows up as undefined on the comment form.

I have a theory, and I'm going to test that out and then perhaps answer my own question.

Comment: Are you sure that `props.user` matches the `like.user` that comes from the backend ? If it is an object and not a string or number, it will never be equal with another object.

Comment: They're both strings. I just console.logged them both to make sure

Comment: Oh wait never mind! that's only the case when the page hasn't reloaded, after that the user shows up as undefined! but it is working in the component that's supposed to pass it the user, so that's where the problem is. I'll update the post now. ty @GabrielePetrioli

Comment: Your are welcome !

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, thanks to Gabriele's comment!

When I mount the `<Post>` component, I set its state for "user" and "loggedIn" with an `axios.get()`. This, as we know, is asynchronous. So the props to the children (including the `<CommentForm>` component) are being sent before the "user" is being set in the state. So since the form's own axios call is based on the "user" being sent in by the `<Post>`, which is undefined when the component is mounted, of course the like's user is not gonna match it!

I fixed it by updating the `<CommentForm>`'s `componentDidMount()`:

```js
componentDidMount () {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3002/u/loggedin',{withCredentials: true}).then(res1=>{
    console.log(res1.data)
    if (!res1.data.loggedIn) return this.props.remove();
    this.setState({user: res1.data.user}) 
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/p/likes/${this.state.post}`).then(res2=>{
      let liked = false;
      for (let like of res2.data) if (like.user == res1.data.user) liked = true;
      this.setState({likes: res2.data, liked})
    })
  })
}
```

It works now!